# Web Performance Testing - Code behind value as dynamic parameter

Tags: c#, performance-testing, web-testing

I've been put in charge of developing a performance test for one aspect of the system my company develops. The idea is that you upload a document, click a button, which then does a whole bunch of steps behind the scenes. The document is given a unique ID once it's uploaded, which I need to capture as a dynamic parameter so that the test can be repeated. The application is written in ASP.NET/C#, and *I have no ability to view the source code or modify it in any way*.

Visual Studio does not automatically pick this up as a dynamic parameter, despite the fact that it needs to be one.

**Process Information**

- The id is generated when the document is uploaded. It's stored in the link that you click to process the document.
- The id is grabbed from the code-behind at run time, through Razor code.
- It is not passed through the referer to the next page, but somehow appears there anyway.

**Things I've Tried**

- Extracting the value from the first page. This just results in having C# put in the id location instead of the actual value. Eg. 'DataItem.GetMember("ObjectId").Value' instead of '600-562949958140473'
- Creating an intermediate step to get the id before moving onto the real page. I'm not sure how to do this successfully - my attempt just resulted in an additional failed step.

This is my first time working with Web Performance Testing, though I have used CodedUI. So for any explanation, please assume I'm an idiot.

Comment: Visual Studio's web test recorder does not find all dynamic data automatically. You need to extract the value from a response. To get more help here you would need to provide much more detail (as text, not as screen captures) of the responses and where the value is needed in the "next" request. I recommend you do some web searching for pages about debugging Visual Studio web performance tests.

Comment: Do not assume that any tool will pick up all dynamic values automagically.  You will have to handle some dynamic elements by hand.  Any other expectation which has been set is leading you down a false path.   This is tool independent